# How does the Pauli Exclusion Principle work in Twistor theory?

Tags: fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, grassmann-numbers, twistor

Twistor theory is described sometimes as a 'natural' way to represent spinor fields.

In QED, we have the Grassmann valued spinor field $\Psi^\alpha(x)$, which naturally leads to the exclusion principle as $\Psi^\alpha(x)\Psi^\alpha(y)= -\Psi^\alpha(y)\Psi^\alpha(x)$. This can be used in the path integral formulation, for example. Alternatively we can say that a wavefunction $\psi(x,y)$ with fermions at $x$ and $y$ is equal to $-\psi(y,x)$

As far as I'm aware standard (non-Palatial) Twistor theory does not have anti-commuting variables.

Thus I presume there is some other 'natural' way to derive the exclusion principle in Twistor theory. Or in other words how would we get anti-symmetric wave functions $\psi(x,y)$ in Twistor theory?

I admit I don't really have a full grasp of Twistor theory, but I am just intrigued to know how one would get the exclusion principle without Grassmann fields as they are essential in the QED path integral approach. (Because this would also give an alternative representation of Grassmann numbers I assume.)

**Edit:**
After further research I have found that Twistor theory may have a special way of multiplying fields like this:

$$\Psi(Z)\star \Psi(W) \overset{def}{=} \frac{\Psi(Z) \Psi(W) }{ (Z \times W)^{2-2s }}$$

where $s$ is the spin. Under this definition $\Psi(Z)\star \Psi(W) = (-1)^{2s}\Psi(W)\star \Psi(Z)$. When the fields are of spin $s$. This seems to make sense although I'm not sure of the details or how this would generalise to three fields.

Comment: You could also ask whether you can define an analogue for anti-commutation relations of creation, annihilation operator in twistor theory. A tentative idea was proposed in 1986 (check pg 4-7 in https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lmason/Tn/TN1-25/No22%204%20Sep%201986.pdf ). I think a more fundamental question one should ask is how to identify the analogue for exclusion principle in standard 2-spinor formalism (which is Grassmann even)

Comment: What is "non-Palatial?"

Comment: @BillOnee "Palatial Twistor Theory" is Penrose's new non-commutative version of Twistor Theory (see Wikipedia). He invented this to try to solve the "Googly Problem" of representing right-handed gravitons in Twistor Theory.

Comment: I have assumed that there is a procedure for, for example, for translating Quantum Electrodynamics into the language of Twistor Theory. Is this true, or have I overestimated the progress in Twistor Theory?

Comment: @zooby you can implement the idea of Ward's construction for YM instanton to calculate tree level diagrams (like Moller and Bhabha scattering) in twistor theory. Palatial twistor construction is equivalent to non-linear graviton construction (as in standard twistor theory) in PT×PT*. Non-commutativity appears even in original twistor theory if you want to introduce cosmological constant term. So you don't have to distinguish b/w standard and palatial twistors